# Custom malloc implementation

Tags: c++, c, memory, malloc, free

Recently I was asked a question to implement a very simple `malloc` with the following restrictions and initial conditions.

```
#define HEAP_SIZE 2048
int main()
{
    privateHeap = malloc(HEAP_SIZE + 256); //extra 256 bytes for heap metadata

    void* ptr = mymalloc( size_t(750) );

    myfree( ptr );
    return 0;

}
```

I need to implement `mymalloc` and `myfree` here using the exact space provided. 256 bytes is nicely mapping to 2048 bits, and I can have a bit array storing if a byte is allocated or if it is free. But when I make a `myfree` call with `ptr`, I cannot tell how much size was allocated to begin with. I cannot use any extra bits.

I don't seem to think there is a way around this, but I've been reiterated that it can be done. Any suggestions ?

## EDIT 1:

1. Alignment restrictions don't exist. I assumed I am not going to align anything.
2. There was a demo program that did a series of `malloc`s and frees to test this, and it didn't have any memory blocks that were small. But that doesn't guarantee anything.

## EDIT 2:

The guidelines from the documentation:
Certain Guidelines on your code:

1. Manage the heap metadata in the private heap; do not create extra linked lists outside of the provided private heap;
2. Design `mymalloc`, `myrealloc`, `myFree` to work for all possible inputs.
3. `myrealloc` should do the following like the `realloc` in C++ library:
   `void* myrealloc( void* C, size_t newSize )`:

   1. If `newSize` is bigger than the size of chunk in `reallocThis`:

      1. It should first try to allocate a chunk of size `newSize` in place so that new chunk's base pointer also is `reallocThis`;
      2. If there is no free space available to do in place allocation, it should allocate a chunk of requested size in a different region;
         and then it should copy the contents from the previous chunk.
      3. If the function failed to allocate the requested block of memory, a `NULL` pointer is returned, and the memory block pointed to 
             by argument `reallocThis` is left unchanged.
   2. If `newSize` is smaller, `realloc` should shrink the size of the chunk and should always succeed.
   3. If `newSize` is 0, it should work like free.
   4. If `reallocThis` is NULL, it should work like `malloc`.
   5. If `reallocThis` is pointer that was already freed, then it should fail gracefully by returning NULL
4. `myFree` should not crash when it is passed a pointer that has already been freed.

Comment: `int main()`, not `void main()`.

Comment: You want to write it in C, and use it in C and C++?

Comment: Hint: What are the alignment guarantees of `malloc`?

Comment: Some information is missing here. How well is your heap expected to perform? Is it supposed to be able to satisfy 2048 1-byte allocations?

Comment: So you can use `privateHeap` to store your data? You don't need to dig in to anything lower?

Comment: Instead of tracking each individual byte, track each individual *allocation*. (And if there's not enough room for another allocation tracking structure in the metadata space, simply return null on that malloc.)

Comment: @Cameron: For 1 byte alignment, offsets/lengths can be stored in 11 bits each, giving a max of 93/2048 allocations.  Not bad.  If they're 8 byte aligned... 8bits, giving 128/256 allocations.  Hm.  16 byte alignment takes 7 bits giving 146/128 allocations.

Comment: @Jon I can share the document with the problem. Is there a way to do that ? (It's a small docx)

Comment: @shrinidhisondur: It would be best to copy/paste the relevant parts into the question. Anything else (linking) risks the link dying in the future.

Comment: @shrinidhisondur: Frankly, I would just tell the interviewer that their problem statement is too loosely specified to attempt a "best effort" solution. Any solution will involve tradeoffs so you have to have at least some general idea of what target you are trying to hit, and would they please be so kind as to give me that idea? You can also briefly describe some imperfect implementations that come to mind (shouldn't be hard) to show them what you mean.

Comment: @shrinidhisondur This is really too broad... At first I believed you wanted to solve a problem: implementing a heap around a buffer, in order to control a RAM budget. But then it appears it's an interview/homework question. In which case, I suggest you have a look at how dlmalloc's mspace feature works: it does exactly what you're asking. Read http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html to understand the data structure and read `mspace_*` functions' implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be thinking of the 256 bytes of meta-data as a bit-map to track free/in-use on a byte-by-byte basis.

I'd consider the following as only one possible alternative:

I'd start by treating the 2048-byte heap as a 1024 "chunks" of 2 bytes each. This gives you 2 bits of information for each chunk. You can treat the first of those as signifying whether that chunk is in use, and the second as signifying whether the following chunk is part of the same logical block as the current one.

When your `free` function is called, you use the passed address to find the correct beginning point in your bitmap. You then walk through bits marking each chunk as free until you reach one where the second bit is set to 0, indicating the end of the current logical block (i.e., that the next 2 byte chunk is not part of the current logical block).

[Oops: just noticed that Ross Ridge already suggested nearly the same basic idea in a comment.]

Answer (score 6):

A common way malloc implementations keep track of the size of memory allocations so `free` knows how big they are is to store the size in the bytes before pointer return by `malloc`. So  say you only need two bytes to store the length, when the caller of `malloc` requests `n` bytes of memory, you actually allocate `n + 2` bytes. You then store the length in the first two bytes, and return a pointer to the byte just past where you stored the size.

As for your algorithm generally, a simple and naive implementation is to keep track of unallocated memory with a linked list of free memory blocks that are kept in order of their location in memory. To allocate space you search for a free block that's big enough. You then modify the free list to exclude that allocation. To free a block you add it back to the free list, coalescing adjacent free blocks.

This isn't a good malloc implementation by modern standards, but a lot of old memory allocators worked this way.

Comment: Suspect the meta heap size of 256 (at least 2048 bits) implies using 2048 bit flags to denote allocated bytes.  But I like the link list size with blocks lopped off in chunks of HEAP_SIZE/256.

Comment: Yah, I don't know what the instructor imagines for an algorithm. It's not obvious to me that a free bitmap and no other information about the allocations is going to produce a significantly better implementation. Or even work, you need somewhere else to store the length of allocations. Maybe have a bitmap with a granularity of two bytes. Two bits are used for every pair of bytes. One bit to record whether the byte pair is allocated and the second to mark the start of an allocation.

Comment: But the extra bytes for each block is metadata, so the total amount of metadata is proportional to the number of blocks allocated. I think however the only way answer to this question is read the instructor's mind and implement the algorithm he expects exactly.

Comment: Revised comment: One _could_ get by with a meta data of only 1 pointer (using remaining meta data for more HEAP): a pointer to link list of unused blocks.  Each allocated block only needs a 1 byte length _index_ and then the user_memory.

Comment: Right about prof mind reading. "total amount of metadata is proportional to the number of blocks allocated" or .... the memory allocations could be in chucks of `HEAP_SIZE/256`, thus fixing the max number of allocations.  IAC - many possibilities and good code may take some time.  Thanks for the feedback. TTFN.